# Would it be useful to have a list of your badges appear when you hovered over the totals in the header?

Tags: feature-request

When I hover over my name I get a super-helpful box with all sorts of statistics about my recent activity on the site and links to the dedicated pages for those metrics. But when I hover over the badge count it only shows the number and color of badges (i.e. the `15 bronze badges` hover text the picture below), which I can obviously already see.

[image: screen shot of badges hover text]

How is this hover text helpful? It's telling me the exact same thing as what I'm hovering over: a picture of a bronze badge and the number 15.

I think it would be more useful to have the existing hover text replaced with a pop-up box showing the list of badges you've earned. New badges could even be highlighted.

I see this as having two major advantages over the prominent badges link at the top of the page:

- it's a hover pop-up not a new page that you have to click-through to or open in another tab
- it's a consolidated list of badges you have actually earned, not a list of all badges available with check marks next to the ones you've earned.

What do others think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel that content that appears on hover should be a summary rather than a list. Also, for a number of users, a list of all the badges they've earned would take up a significant portion of the page, and in some cases, it simply wouldn't fit. (It would also increase the size of the page, significantly in certain cases, like with users who have lots of badges and choose to display fewer questions per page.)

Now, if hovering over badges could produce something similar to hovering over your name, I could support that idea. Maybe a list of badges earned in the last week, or the five most recent badges you earned and the dates on which you earned them ...

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was thinking. The interface when you're not hovering would stay exactly as it is, but when you hover would show different information. Agreed that a comprehensive list is probably neither helpful nor feasible, especially for folks with lots of badges, but some filter of the most recent ones, and the date they were earned would more interesting than repeating information already on the screen.

Answer (score -3):

I think a list of badges would be useful. One could "navigate" to get them, but it's helpful to have everything in one place.

Comment: You mean this link that's on the front page?  http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges

Comment: @little bobby tables: You may have a point that this process may be logistically complicated. But I was echoing a point made by another member. Perhaps we can work out a reasonable compromise solution like setting up a link to the page with the badges. That would satisfy my definition of "everything in one place."

Comment: I don't follow you at all.  I didn't say anything about the process being logistically complicated; I pointed out that there is already a list of badges on the front page.  How does this not satisfy "a list of badges" that one could "navigate" to?

Comment: @littlebobbytables: actually you have a point. The point that I believe Adam was trying to make was that there was some "white space" next to the biographical information, where you could put badges, certainly a convenience. On the other hand, your counter-argument, which I earlier accepted, was that there was a link to the badges on the front page.

Comment: @littlebobbytables not at all what I was thinking about. I've updated the question to be more clear. If this helps I'd be interested in if you think it would be an improvement over the status quo. I did know about the badges page you mention.

Comment: I support Adam's updated proposal.